# Добавить класс к ссылке

Tags: jquery

Есть меню. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на любой из пунктов меню - он подчеркивался черной линией. При нажатии на следующий пункт меню - в предыдущем подчеркивание пропадало, а в новом - появлялось.

Вот мой код:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.topmenulink').click(
    function() {
      $( this ).removeClass('activelink');
    }, function() {
      $( this ).addClass('activelink');
    }
  );
});
</script>
```

```css
.activelink {
color: #222;
border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<span id="left-top-menu"><a class="topmenulink" href="/zhenschinam/">Женщинам</a></span>
<span id="left-top-menu"><a class="topmenulink" href="/muzhchinamm/">Мужчинам</a></span>
<span id="left-top-menu"><a class="topmenulink" href="/detjamd/">Детям</a></span>
```

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на ссылку - страница перезагружается и подчеркивание появляется только на момент нажатия и потом пропадает.

Вот живой пример:
https://bigcitymart.ru/

Comment: с чего ты взял, что в метод click можно передавать две функции?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Классика жанра. Надо снимать класс со всех ссылок, на всякий случай и добавлять тому, на который нажали:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.wrapper').on('click', '.topmenulink', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.topmenulink').removeClass('activelink');
        $( this ).addClass('activelink');
    });
});
```

```css
.activelink {
color: #222;
border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <span id="left-top-menu"><a class="topmenulink" href="/zhenschinam/">Женщинам</a></span>
  <span id="left-top-menu"><a class="topmenulink" href="/muzhchinamm/">Мужчинам</a></span>
  <span id="left-top-menu"><a class="topmenulink" href="/detjamd/">Детям</a></span>
</div>
```

А перезагружается страница потому, что нажимаете на ссылку, а для нее срабатывает дефолтное поведение: идти по ссылке. Чтобы этого небыло, надо предотвращать поведение через `e.preventDefault();` например.

**P.S.** у вас  у всех `span` стоит один идентификатор `left-top-menu`. Так делать не стоит!

Comment: Все работает так как нужно, спасибо.

Только по ссылкам не переходит.
Можно как-то этот момент пофиксить?

Comment: @Arthyr так а на кой тогда ты пытаешься менять класс через JS, если тебе надо по ссылкам переходить? Ты определись, либо ты переключаешь их в JS и подгружаешь контент через ajax, либо переходишь, по ссылкам с перезагрузкой страницы, тогда проставлять класс надо при генерировании страницы в php

Comment: Нужна реализация, как на http://www.lamoda.ru .
К сожалению я знаю как этот момент обыграть, по этому и обратился на stackoverflow.

Comment: @Arthyr ну собсн я написал выше. либо перезагрузка и классы ставь при генерации, либо подгрузка контента через ajax (или pjax) и тогда классы менять можно через js.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.topmenulink').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // предотвращаем стандартное поведение перехода по ссылке
  $('.topmenulink').removeClass('activelink'); // убираем класс у всех кнопок
  $(this).addClass('activelink'); // добавляем класс нажатой кнопке
});
```

```css
.activelink {
  color: #222;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #222;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="left-top-menu"><a class="topmenulink" href="/zhenschinam/">Женщинам</a></span>
<span id="left-top-menu"><a class="topmenulink" href="/muzhchinamm/">Мужчинам</a></span>
<span id="left-top-menu"><a class="topmenulink" href="/detjamd/">Детям</a></span>
```